# The type must be a non-nullable value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, concurrentdictionary

I'm trying to create a NativeArray of type Dictionary and i get this error:

> The type `Realtime.Messaging.Internal.ConcurrentDictionary<string,Chunk>' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as type parameter`T' in the generic type or method `Unity.Collections.NativeArray'

```
NativeArray<ConcurrentDictionary<string, Chunk>> dictionary = new NativeArray<ConcurrentDictionary<string, Chunk>>(8, Allocator.TempJob);
```

I'm new to Unity and C#, this question was probably asked before but i've been searching for a fix and couldn't find anything.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think this is not the problem...may be where you used it. do you have any nullable type like int? char? something like that?

Comment: Since that's used to share a chunk of memory between managed an unmanaged it's restricted to types that have a fixed size and cannot be a reference type like a dictionary.  What are you trying to do that you think you need to put a dictionary into a NativeArray in the first place?

Comment: @juharr Sorry for late response, i'm trying to make a procedural world and that dictionary has all the blocks that needs to be drawn and i want to draw them on a seperate thread, which can't access to chunks variable.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is in the error message you get: *.. must be a non-nullable value type...* ConcurrentDictionary is a reference type and it seems that NativeArray has a type parameter constraint to accept only structs, the kind of constraint as the following:

```
class Foo<T> where T:struct{}
```

This means that you can only create NativeArray of value types (structs): int, byte, char, ...etc, or your own structs...